# Getting repeated data white using django orm

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-serializer

im filtering that user whoes `order_status` is completed and who have `listing_id` 5001.  But im getting output data repeated

Here is my Code:

> models.py

```
class Users(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    '''

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'users'

class UserOrder2(models.Model):
    order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    order_status = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='None')
    listing_id = models.CharField(max_length=250,default='None')
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="user_id")
    '''

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user_order'

class UserOrderProduct2(models.Model):
    order_id = models.ForeignKey(UserOrder2, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="order_id")
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user_order_product'
```

> Views.py

```
class UserPurchaseQuantityView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    def post(self, request):
        listing_id= request.data.get('listing_id')

        kwargs = {}
        kwargs['userorder2__listing_id'] = listing_id
        kwargs['userorder2__order_status'] = 'Order Delivered'
        queryset = Users.objects.filter(**kwargs)
        data = UsersSerializer(queryset, many=True).data
        return Response(data)
```

> serializers.py

```
class UserOrderProductSerializer2(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ["product_id", "product_quantity", "product_price", "sub_total",
                  "product_name"]
        model = UserOrderProduct2


class UserOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_detail = UserOrderProductSerializer2(source="userorderproduct2_set", many=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ["user_id", "order_date", "product_detail"]
        model = UserOrder2

class UsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_detail = UserOrderSerializer(source="userorder2_set", many=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = "__all__"
        model = Users
```

I'm getting repeated output like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 51238,
        "name": "aaa",
        "phone": "123456789",
        "email": "aaa@gmail.com",
        "user_detail": [
        {
            "user_id": 51238,
            "order_date": "2021-07-27 15:55:56"
            "product_detail": [
                {
                    "product_id": 20767,
                    "product_quantity": 1,
                    "product_price": 150.0,
                    "sub_total": 150.0,
                    "product_name": "EMINAZ 2mg Tablet 10's"
                    
            ]
    },
    {
        "id": 51238,
        "name": "aaa",
        "phone": "123456789",
        "email": "aaa@gmail.com",
        "user_detail": [
        {
            "user_id": 51238,
            "order_date": "2021-07-27 15:55:56"
            "product_detail": [
                {
                    "product_id": 20767,
                    "product_quantity": 1,
                    "product_price": 150.0,
                    "sub_total": 150.0,
                    "product_name": "EMINAZ 2mg Tablet 10's"
                    
            ]        },
    {
        "id": 51238,
        "name": "aaa",
        "phone": "123456789",
        "email": "aaa@gmail.com",
        "user_detail": [
        {
            "user_id": 51238,
            "order_date": "2021-07-27 15:55:56"
            "product_detail": [
                {
                    "product_id": 20767,
                    "product_quantity": 1,
                    "product_price": 150.0,
                    "sub_total": 150.0,
                    "product_name": "EMINAZ 2mg Tablet 10's"
                    
            ]        } ]
```

Comment: are those doc strings intentional? i mean those \` symbols

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in **kwargs. Try this

```
class UserPurchaseQuantityView(generics.GenericAPIView):
def post(self, request):
    listing_id= request.data.get('listing_id')
    queryset = Users.objects.filter(userorder2__listing_id=listing_id, 
               userorder2__order_status='Order Delivered')
    data = UsersSerializer(queryset, many=True).data
    return Response(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `distinct()` to make unique.

```
queryset = Users.objects.filter(**kwargs).distinct()
```

Comment: Do you know why it's duplicating?

Comment: @bdbd I think the problem from subtable `UserOrder2` of User and Order.